# Is it possible to have a list view of OpportunityLineItemSchedule?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list-view, opportunity-lineitem

I'm trying to create a list view of OpportunityLineItemSchedule but I have this error message

> Error: afterRender threw an error in 'lightning:listView'
> [[lightning:listView] Unsupported objectApiName: null

So I was wondering if the use of OpportunityLineItemSchedule was possible with a List View lightning component? If not let me know what is the best solution in order to have slighty the same result? A datatable?

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="ListViewController">
    
 <!-- call doInit js function on component load to fetch list view details-->   
<aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!-- aura attributes -->   

    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="olis" type="Object"/>

    
<!-- lightning List View : https://sforce.co/2Q4sebt--> 
<lightning:listView objectApiName="{!v.olis}"
                listName="AllSchedule"
                rows="5"
                showSearchBar="true"
                showActionBar="false"
                enableInlineEdit="true"
                showRowLevelActions="false"
                />
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var action = component.get('c.getOlis');
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.olis', response.getReturnValue());
                //console.log(cmp.get('v.mydata'));
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'OpportunityLineItem.Product2.Name', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'ScheduleDate', type: 'date', typeAttributes: {month: 'long',year: 'numeric'}},
            { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Revenue', type: 'currency', editable: true},
            { label: 'Validated', fieldName: 'Validated__c', type: 'boolean', editable: true}
        ])
        
    }
})
```

**Apex:**

```
public class ListViewController {
    
   @AuraEnabled
    public static List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> getOlis(){
        List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> olis =
                [Select OPPORTUNITYLINEITEMID, OpportunityLineItem.Product2.Name, SCHEDULEDATE, Revenue, Validated__c 
                        from OpportunityLineItemSchedule    
                        Order by SCHEDULEDATE ASC, OPPORTUNITYLINEITEMID ASC];
        
        return olis;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking, only objects that have UI tabs have list views. Since the Opportunity Line Item Schedule object doesn't have its own tab, there's no list view support, either (there are a few exceptions, but this isn't one of them). You can query the data and show it in a lightning:datatable, as you've guessed, but that's about it. Standard list view features (including StandardSetController and Visualforce's listView component) will not support this object. FYI, you should be able to describe the object and look at the `listviewable` attribute. When true, you can use list views on this object, otherwise not.